# error in htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Anyone help me to correct the following code

I want to disable the direct access from users but the Apache can do it

```
<Files f1.php, f2.html>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: `but the apach canr do it` what does that mean

Comment: canr => can, can you recorrect the code

Comment: Sounds like you want to prevent hot linking? See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=htaccess+prevent+hot+linking

Answer (score 1):

Multiple files are not allowed in `<Files>` directive, break it into 2 and use it like this:

```
<Files f1.php>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

<Files f2.html>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```